# How to use multiple sys.exit() with different return codes inside a try except block in python

Tags: python, exception, return-code

I have a python script which is called as a `subprocess` from a parent script. In this script I have multiple `if` statements inside a `try` block and I do `sys.exit()` with different return code from these `if` statements. The structure of the code is this way:

```
def func3():

    try:

        # bunch of other code
        if condition1:
            print 'condition 1'
            sys.exit(1)
        if condition2:
            print 'condition 2'
            sys.exit(0)
         .
         .
         .


    except:
        print 'In the except'
        #what sys.exit() to put here

if __name__ == '__main__':

    func3()
```

I know it is not a good way to write this way but I have to use `try` as there are many different parts of the code which may result in some error and also the `if` conditions depends on the execution and result of these codes.

Now the problem is that how can I put this code so that it successfully does a `sys.exit()` with appropriate exit code. What `sys.exit()` should I put in the `except` section as if I do a `sys.exit(1)` from inside the `try` and `sys.exit(0)` from inside the `except` then the return code will be `0` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You are playing Pokemon here; you are catching them **all**. Don't do that.

At most catch `Exception`; the `SystemExit` exception thrown by `sys.exit()` doesn't inherit from `Exception` (only from `BaseException`) and will simply be passed through:

```
try:
    # ...
except Exception:
    # ...
```

`SystemExit`, together with `GeneratorExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` should rarely be caught anyway, which is why they are the only 3 exceptions that do not derive from `Exception`. See the [*Exception hierarchy* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

If you *must* catch the `SystemExit`, you can read the exit code from the `code` attribute:

```
try:
    # ...
except SystemExit as sysexit:
    sys.exit(sysexit.code)
```

Comment: so what solution should I use to force my code from each `if` statement (if it is true) to go to `except` block? The errors that may come are not generic type.

Comment: @JasonDonnald: you want to *avoid* the except block when using `sys.exit()`. All other exceptions are still caught.

Comment: What I meant that is there any other way that I can force the code to go to the except block from the the `if` conditions (without any sys.exit() from if condition) and then do the `sys.exit()` with appropriate exit code from the except section? I know I can use `raise` but with `raise` we have to specify a exception type right? My exceptions are not generic types

Comment: @JasonDonnald: why not use a *function* and return something? You can also create a custom exception to jump out of the code to the exception handler (`raise MyCustomException()`), and even combine that with a function (raise in the function if you need to signal a non-regular return).

Comment: using `return` does not serves my purpose as I am calling the above script as a subprocess from another script and gettign the appropriate return code back to parent script is what I want. If I use `return 0` or `return 1` then all the time I will get return code as 0 in parent script as the return from function will make to code to return to `main()` of the same script and not the parent script

Comment: @JasonDonnald: so why is just using `sys.exit()` in the right places not enough? Your problem description is far from clear here.

Comment: in my current code if I just use `sys.exit()` in each `if` statement then that value gets overwritten by the except block

Comment: @JasonDonnald so don't use such an except block. I have already told you how not to catch the `sys.exit()` exception.